# XAML - How to check if a ComboBox is populated.. a better way to write this code

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Feels like there should be a more elegant way to write this code?

```
 try
 {
    if (InfrastructureComboBoxT32.Items[0] == null){}
 }
 catch
 {
    // Load data into the combobox
 }
```

Using Silverlight5

Comment: If you are using Linq, you can use !InfrastructureComboBoxT31.Items.Any()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
items != null && items.Count > 0
```

Comment: Thanks - went with InfrastructureComboBoxT31.Items.Count == 0

Answer (score 0):

The [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control exposes a [HasItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.hasitems%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property. Then:

```
if(!InfrastructureComboBoxT32.HasItems)
{
    // Load data into the combobox
}
```

Comment: Got:'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.HasItems' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: It seems the HasItems property is protected in Silverlight. What an odd thing, the WPF counterpart is public and bindable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx